# Getting an error 'string index out of range'

Tags: python

I'm new to programming in python and i'm getting this strange error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/python/caeser hacker.py", line 27, in <module>
    translated = translated + LETTERS[num]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Any solutions?

Full code:

```python
#caeser cipher hacker
#hhtp://inventwithpython.com/hacking {bsd licensed}

message='GUVF VF ZL FRPERG ZRFFNTR.'
LETTERS='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

#loop through every possiable key
for key in range (len(LETTERS)):

    #it is important to set translated to blank string so that the
    #previous iteration's value for translated is cleared.
    translated=''

    #the rest of the program is the same as the caeser program.
for symbol in message:
    if symbol in LETTERS:
        #GET THE ENCRYPTED (OR DECRYPTED) NUMBER FOR THIS SYMBOL
        num= LETTERS.find(symbol) # get the number of the symbol
        num = num - key

        # handle the wrap-around if num is larger that the length of
        #LETTERS or less than 0
        if num >= 0:
           num = num +len(LETTERS)

        # add encrypted/decrypted numbers at the end of translad
        translated = translated + LETTERS[num]

    else:
         # just add the symbol without encrypting/decrypting
         translated = translated + symbol

#print the encrypted/decrypted string to the screen
print(translated)

# copy the encrypted /decrypted string to the clipboard
```

Comment: Stop trying to access positions of the string that don't exist.

Comment: What makes you think that the position `len(LETTERS) + some_positive_integer_value` should exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines push `num` well outside the allowed range of indices:

```
# handle the wrap-around if num is larger that the length of
#LETTERS or less than 0
if num >= 0:
   num = num +len(LETTERS)
```

Now `num` is *guaranteed* to be equal to or greater than `len(LETTERS)`, which is an invalid index.

Perhaps you meant to use `%` modulus instead?

```
# handle the wrap-around if num is larger that the length of
#LETTERS or less than 0
num %= len(LETTERS)
```

The `%` modulus operator *would* constrain the value to the range `[0, len(LETTERS))` (so 0 is included, `len(LETTERS)` is *excluded*, which are the exact values that are allowed for an index into `LETTERS`.